# CORS and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, backbone.js, cors, jsessionid

I am having a problem with Tomcat and backbone using CORS.
The setup is as followed:
 - Backbone sends a post request to tomcat
 - Tomcat checks using web.xml and custom filter (link: [CORS FILTER IN JAVA](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html)) and uses CORS on this request
 - request gets processed through the CORS filter and matches
 - Response is sent back to backbone and fails.

Backbone does 2 request, first 1 is a preflight request and returns a 200 status (which is good), second request returns a 302 status because my jsessionid gets changed and wants to redirect to login page which fails (not ok).

In backbone I have already added this:

```
data: param,
    // contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    //async: true,
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
```

And in tomcat this:

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8888 http://localhost:8881</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified, X-File-Name</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>3600</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

But still no luck. My JSESSIONID doesn't get send to my tomcat and that causes a new JSESSIONID to be created and makes my request fail.

Any help would be useful :)

I am using Tomcat 6.0.16 and Jquery 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `dataType` to `'json'`.